# How can I simplify the setting of font and background colors in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am doing it like this:

1) set up  a style with colors:

```
public class Styles
{
    public static Color[] LineColor = { greyF2, grey28, grey28 };
```

2) My application has a value of 1,2 or 2  for the style and the color is set like this:

```
Current.Resources["ShellBackgroundColor"]   = Styles.ShellBackgroundColor[thc];
```

Is there a way that I could simplify the coding of these two lines above?

Comment: According to your description, you want to set current contentpage font and background color in Xamarin.Forms shell? If yes, I suggest you can take a look the Xamarin.Forms Shell Page Configuration:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration